# How can I run functions within a Vue data object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So I am trying to use the following component within Vue JS:

```
Vue.component('careers', {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>',

  data: function() {

    var careerData = [];

    client.getEntries()
    .then(function (entries) {
      // log the title for all the entries that have it
      entries.items.forEach(function (entry) {
        if(entry.fields.jobTitle) {
          careerData.push(entry);
        }
      })
    });

    return careerData;
  }
});
```

The following code emits an error like so:

```
[Vue warn]: data functions should return an object:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function 
(found in component <careers>)
```

However as you can see I am running a foreach through all of my Contentful `entries`, then each object within entries is being pushed to an array, I then try to return the array but I get an error.

Any idea how I can extract all of my `entries` to my data object within my component?

When I use the `client.getEntries()` function outside of my Vue component I get the following data:

[image]

Comment: error says that the data function must return an `Object`, not an `Array`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First thing first - keep your data model as clean as possible - so no methods there.

Second thing, as error says, when you are dealing with data into component, data should be function that returns an object:

```
Vue.component('careers', {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>',

  data: function() {
    return {
     careerData: []
    }
  }
});
```

As I write, data fetching and other logic shouldn't be in the data, there is an object reserved for that in Vue.js called `methods`.

So move your logic into the methods, and when you have received the data, you can assign it to `careerData` like this:

```
this.careerData = newData
```

or push things to the array like you did before. And then at the end, you can call the method on some lifecycle hooks:

```
Vue.component('careers', {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>',

  data: function() {
    return {
      careerData: []
    }
  },

  created: function() {
    this.fetchData();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      // your fetch logic here
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ahhh this makes so much more sense to me now. Thanks for spreading the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you are forced to have functions inside data object, for example when posting data and functions to some framework components (e.g. element-ui [shortcuts in datepicker](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker#enter-date)). Because data in vue is actually a function, you can declare functions inside it before the return statement:

```
export default {
data() {
  let onClick = (picker) => {
    picker.$emit('pick', new Date());
    this.myMethod();
  }

  return {
    pickerOptions: {
      shortcuts: [{
        text: 'Today',
        onClick: onClick
      }]}
  };
},
methods:{
  myMethod(){
    console.log("foo")
  }
},
};
```

You can point with this to the methods if you wish. It is not particularly clean as possible but it may come handy sometimes.